# Разместить текст на изображении

Tags: html, css, изображения

Подскажите, как разместить текст поверх изображения, чтобы было как на картинке?

```html
<div class="works-image">
  <img src="img/works_1.jpg" width="310px" alt="">
  <img src="img/works_2.jpg" width="295px" alt="">
  <img src="img/works_3.jpg" width="295px" alt="">
</div>
```

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 3):

А бекграунд не вариант?

```css
.works-image {
  background: url(https://404store.com/2017/09/17/Spa-still-life-with-bamboo-fountain-and-zen-stone.jpg);
  width: 33vw;
  height: 33vw;
  background-size: cover;
}

.works-image .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.5333333vw;
  transition:1s opacity;
}

.works-image:hover .overlay {
  
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="works-image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="content">
      Текст
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.image {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.image .text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://static.tumblr.com/3d9ac85fda4c928fbf020185e2aab0c5/ecuyhbw/inIon7mm9/tumblr_static_badr4s3xiooc4sosgokwosk0s_640_v2.jpg">
  <div class="text">Title</div>
</div>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hb8ozpuy/3/)

Comment: хороший ответ (+) На мой взгляд текст крупнее надо сделать и выбрать белый цветЮ а то он совсем теряется в сетке

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, это всё легко поправимо, я лишь написал реализацию)

Answer (score 1):

Создайте отдельный блок с текстом,
и поставьте картинкам `position: absolute`

```css
.works-image {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="works-image">
  <img src="img/works_1.jpg" width="310px" alt="">
  <img src="img/works_2.jpg" width="295px" alt="">
  <img src="img/works_3.jpg" width="295px" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; /* для IE 6 */
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 466px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

h2 span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 55px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
  <h2><span>текст<br />поверх изображения</span></h2>
</div>
```